# Fetching emails from Gmail using (mainly) the Rust standard library

Tags: openssl, gmail, imap, rust

I'd like to fetch my GMail email using Rust.
I'm currently using the [rust-openssl](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl.git) library and the `TcpStream` class from the standard library.

The problem I encountered is simple: the following code is "stuck" between `println!("0")` and `println!("1")` in the `login` method. The stream is suddenly "frozen".

Nonetheless, it works perfectly when performing HTTP requests to another URL.

```
extern crate openssl;

use std::io::{IoResult, TcpStream};
use openssl::ssl::{SslContext, Sslv23, SslStream, SslVerifyPeer};

pub struct GmailSocket {
    _stream: SslStream<TcpStream>
}

impl GmailSocket {
    pub fn connect() -> IoResult<GmailSocket> {
        let tcpstream = try!(TcpStream::connect("imap.gmail.com", 993));
        let mut sslcontext = SslContext::new(Sslv23);
        match sslcontext.set_CA_file("./cert.pem") {
            None => {},
            Some(e) => fail!("{}", e)
        }
        sslcontext.set_verify(SslVerifyPeer, None);
        let sslstream = SslStream::new(&sslcontext, tcpstream);
        Ok(GmailSocket {_stream: sslstream})
    }

    pub fn login(&mut self, username: &str, password: &str) -> IoResult<bool> {
        let req = format!("L01 LOGIN {:s} {:s}\r\n", username, password);
        try!(self._stream.write_str(req.as_slice()));
        println!("0");
        match try!(self._stream.read_to_string()) {
            res => println!("{}", res)
        }
        println!("1");
        Ok(true)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut gmail_socket = match GmailSocket::connect() {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(e) => fail!("{}", e)
    };
    gmail_socket.login("account@gmail.com", "password");
}
```

Does the problem come from the SSL certification file, the format of the IMAP requests, the code or the method used itself? Is OAuth mandatory for such a task?

Also, the `./cert.pem` file has been generated with this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
    -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout cert.pem -out cert.pem
```

Since the main purpose of this exercise is educational, I'd like to avoid using [rust-http](https://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http).

Comment: rust-http won’t help you with IMAP… well, the standard situation that leads to this is where the server is waiting for something additional, and you’re not sending it. Probably, if you wait long enough it will kill the connection. I suggest you take a closer look at the IMAP specs and try thus to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: That code looks plausible provided that your password contains only the most boring kind of ascii nonwhitespace. See if you can issue the exact same command, with the correct password, using "openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf". As an aside, you may find it more comfortable to experiment with an IMAP server where you can read the error/debug log files.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the [imap crate](https://crates.io/crates/imap).

I think your problem is coming from the format of the IMAP requests, which follow a specific protocol.

With the imap crate, you can easily connect to an inbox over SSL like so:

```
fn connect_to_email() -> IMAPStream {
    match IMAPStream::connect("imap.gmail.com",
                              993,
                              Some(SslContext::new(SslMethod::Sslv23).unwrap())) {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(e) => panic!("connect to email {}", e),
    }
}
```

Then, to actually grab emails, you can select a folder and then fetch the appropriate text:

```
imap_socket.select("INBOX")
imap_socket.fetch(str_num, "BODY[TEXT]")
imap_socket.fetch(str_num, "BODY[HEADER]")
```

where `imap_socket : &mut IMAPStream` and `str_num : &str` (index of email in your inbox, which is sorted by timestamp).

Comment: The question explicitly wants to know how to do it "mostly with the standard library", but this recommends another library.

Comment: @Shepmaster The answer doesn't have to be *perfect* to be useful. Imap crate is a good pointer, the OP can look there to figure out his problem.